# DataTable DateTime Formatting Issue

Tags: c#, datetime, datatables

Ok so I have a Column in my `DataTable` that is a `DateTime`, it must remain a `DateTime` so that it will sort properly.  The problem is I can't get it to format in MM/dd/yyyy format like I need. Below is the code for my method that formats the `DateTable` and creates a new formatted one out of it, this is the only column I am having issues formatting.  It always comes back like `01/15/2014 12:00:00 AM`

```
private DataTable formatDataTable17(DataTable dt)
{
    DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        // Checks to see if the column name is date
        // if it is, then change the datatype of that
        // column to date time.
        if(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToLower() == "date")
        {
            dtNew.Columns.Add(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName, typeof(DateTime));
        }
        else
        { 
            dtNew.Columns.Add(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName, typeof(String));
        }

    }        
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow newRow = dtNew.NewRow();

        //newRow[0] = dt.Rows[i][0];  //Date 
        newRow[0] = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
        newRow[1] = dt.Rows[i][1];  //CICS Region
        newRow[2] = dt.Rows[i][2];  //Transaction
        newRow[3] = dt.Rows[i][3];  //LPAR
        newRow[4] = String.Format("{0:0.000000}", dt.Rows[i][4]);  //CPU Per Transaction
        newRow[5] = String.Format("{0:###,###,##0}", dt.Rows[i][5]);  //Transaction Count
        newRow[6] = String.Format("{0:###,###,##0.00}", dt.Rows[i][6]);  //MIPS Rate
        newRow[7] = String.Format("{0:0.000000}", dt.Rows[i][7]);  //MIPS Usage

        dtNew.Rows.Add(newRow);

    }
```

Comment: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: `string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt.Rows[i][0].ToString())` does not work, because you cannot format a string. Remove the `.ToString()`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I have done it without .ToString() and get the same result.  I have tried DateTime.ParseExact and still keeps the same format.  I can't change my gridview either because it holds other stuff besides dates

Comment: You must pass a `DateTime` to the format function, otherwise it will not work. If `dt.Rows[i][0]` contains a string it will keep the format of this string. Formatting is the process of converting a binary value into a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `DataTable` is just a place to store your data.

The way it's presented (formatted) for the user should be handled by whatever control you decide to use to display the data in the `DataTable`.

For example, if you were using a `DataGridView` (WinForms), you might have code like this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

dataGridView1.Columns["date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
```

You don't need that `formatDataTable17()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
newRow[0] = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][0]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```